# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'WSGIRequest'

Tags: django, django-middleware

need to create middleware that stores all requests and execution time in Django.
I created a column in db

models.py

```
class RequestInformation(models.Model):
   list_of_requests = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And also looked through django docs and created middleware.py

```
from profileapp.models import RequestInformation

class CustomRequestMiddleware(object):
   def process_request(self, request):
      http_information = RequestInformation(request)
      http_information.save()
```

Also added custom middleware in settings. But don't know what to do next.

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a 
number, not 'WSGIRequest'
```

Sorry fo stupid question, didn't find ho to solve this.Thanks in advance

Comment: There should be a init method and also a call method ( executed on each request automatically) please read the docs again https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/

Answer (score 1):

The first positional argument to a model instance is the pk, which is an int. Usually you use keyword arguments to specify the fields instead: `RequestInformation(list_of_requests=request)`.

However, this still won't do anything useful, as it will just save a string representation of the request object. If you want to get anything useful out of that object, you would need to access its attributes individually and allocate then to separate fields in the model.